# NelmioApiDocBundle set Response content type as file

Tags: symfony, swagger, php-7, symfony5, nelmioapidocbundle

I am using NelmioApiDocBundle 4.0 to generate the documentation of my API. The problem started when i tried to set a response type as a file. I have a method that gets a file from database and returns it as StreamedResponse:

```
return new StreamedResponse(function () use ($consent) {
                    fpassthru($consent);
                    exit();
                }, 200, [
                    'Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary',
                    'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
                    'Content-Disposition' => sprintf('attachment; filename="%s.pdf"', 'filename'),
                    'Content-Length' => fstat($consent)['size'],
                ]);
```

This code works well and return the requested file but i can't set appropriate response type in the documentation.
I tried [this way](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-responses/#response-that-returns-a-file), so mi annotations look like this:

```
     * @OA\Response(
     *     response=200,
     *     description="My description",
     *     content="application/pdf",
     *     @OA\Schema(
     *      type="string",
     *      format="binary"
     *    )
     * )
```

but the response is:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

The problems starts when i set the **content** property, but without it
[this is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGniK.png)

Comment: It looks like you need to put `@OA\Schema` inside `@OA\MediaType` - see [this example](https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php/issues/766). Does this work?

Comment: I tried and it worked, thanks, put your comment as response, so i can accept it like correct answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put `@OA\Schema` inside `@OA\MediaType`:

```php
     * @OA\Response(
     *     response=200,
     *     description="My description",
     *     @OA\MediaType(
     *         mediaType="application/pdf",
     *         @OA\Schema(
     *            type="string",
     *            format="binary"
     *         )
     *     )
     * )
```